# merge や revert において commit message の要約部分が長くなってしまう場合は、どうするべき？

Tags: git

merge や revert を行う際の、デフォルトのコミットメッセージは、 merge の場合はブランチ名から、 revert の際には commit message から自動的に生成されます。

```
Merge branch 'BRANCH-X' into BRANCH-Y

Revert "Some Commit Message"
```

`man git-commit` によれば、コミットメッセージの要約部分(最初の行) は 50 字以内に抑えるのが望ましい(desirable)、とありますが、それを超えてしまうような要約メッセージがデフォルトで表示される merge, revert の場合には、どんなメッセージの要約部分を記述するのが git として行儀のよい方法になるのでしょうか。

Comment: 50文字は最初の１行目に書く要約のことですよ。１行あけて本文に詳細を書くのは全く問題ないですし、むしろ推奨されています。`commit -m "blah"`の１行コメントだけで済ましがちですが、本来本文を書くべきです。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi あ、すいません、その要約について、 merge や revert のときに、デフォルトだと長くなってしまうのをどうしたらよいのか、が知りたいことでした。質問を修正しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Though not required, it’s a good idea to begin the commit message with a single short (less than 50 character) line summarizing the change, followed by a blank line and then a more thorough description. The text up to the first blank line in a commit message is treated as the commit title, and that title is used throughout Git.
>   <sub>--- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion より引用</sub>

変更点の要約を50文字以内で書き、そのあとに1行空けて詳細な説明を書くとよい、という話ですね。

もしデフォルトのコミットメッセージが適切でないのだとしたら、`git commit` のように自分で指定させるような仕様になっているでしょう。そうでないのですから、あえて変更する必要はないと考えます。

例えば中身の詰まった長文を自分で書いた場合は、50文字で切り取られるとまずいということもありますが、問題のデフォルトメッセージの大半はブランチ名や別のコミットメッセージです。これらの場合、冒頭部分だけ読めれば「ああ、あれのことね」と察することができるので、たとえ50文字を超えたところで省略されてしまってもさほど問題にはならないと思います。

しいて言えば、イレギュラーなmergeのタイトルに何か目印を付けたり、revertした理由をコミットメッセージ本文に書いておくと、後で見直すときにわかりやすいかもしれませんね。